# Laravel 7 Api auth always return false

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I have Jwt auth system.(Laravel 7)
With this controller:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function signin(SigninForm $request)
    {
        $token = JWTAuth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));
        return response()->json(['Authorization' => $token]);
    }
}
```

With this model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable, SoftDeletes;

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

config/auth.php:

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

    ],
```

I try OpenServer and Xampp for server.
Settings suitable for development: msql 8.0, php 7.4.
Some time in new project auth system work, but after some time or reboot his always return false.
I try `composer dump-autoload`,`php artisan optimize`,`php artisan optimize:clear`,`php artisan config:clear`, but it does not work.Anybody have this problem?

Comment: Do you get anything in the log or similar?

Comment: Nothing about that.

Comment: I am clear logs and then try login get false and nothing in logs.

Comment: I think its possible after some time the token to expire and also after reboot to have new session/cookie?

Comment: @thefallen
No, because I try with 3 projects and in first all work(after reboot), second does not work after install get false, third stop work after error seeder. And always when I have error with seeder (not with migration) auth system return always false.